# How do I change the profile of the NServiceBus Generic Host when it is installed as a windows service?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I have a server with several instances of the NServiceBus Generic Host installed as Windows Services to host my publishers and subscribers.  Now that I am nearing the end of development, I would like to switch these services from running in the default profile (Lite) to the Integration profile for some additional testing.  After reading the notes found here:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/profiles

it would appear that this is possible, but I'm having trouble finding documentation on how this is done.  Do I need to modify the NServiceBus.Host.exe.config file in some way, modify the app.config, or some other change to cause the service to run in a different profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide the profile on the command line after the other options.  In your case this is "NServiceBus.Integration"

Comment: This is an installed service.  Are you saying I need to uninstall the service and then re-install the service with the profile in the install command line?  I had hoped that there would be some mechanism to switch this without requiring that I uninstall / re-install each time I want to change the profile.

Comment: You could not manage it as a service and just run the host exe to change the profile by stop/starting the exe.  Otherwise, you have to reinstall.

Comment: Launching the host with different profiles from the command line is fine during development, but I'm working towards a production deployment.  The NServiceBus documentation under the section "Specifying which profiles to run" which reads "all profiles that are provided become baked into the installation" led me to believe that I could change the profile of the service.